# Using an if statement to send result back to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, if-statement

I want a way where the user enters details through a series of radio buttons. A java class then does some work by looking at the responses and returning a score to the user based on the responses (i.e. a different response can give different feedback). ive written the code for the jsps and now need some way it can link to the java class containing the if statement, go through the if statement and then return the result.

the first jsp where the radio buttons are selected

```
<form:form action="/HelloSpring/questionTwo" method="post">

    <p> What is the correct wrapper class for the primitive int? </p>
    <input type="radio" name="radios1" value="Int" path="types" >Int<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radios1" value="Enum" path="types">Enum<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radios1" value="integer" path="types" >integer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radios1" value="Integer" path="types" >Integer<br>

             <input type="submit" value="Next" >

</form:form >
```

the controller where it should read results and then perform if statement

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String results(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response){


                String radio = (String)request.getParameter("radios1");
                request.setAttribute("total", total);

//                model.addAttribute("total", total);

                if (radio.equals("Int")){
                    total = total + 0;
                }
                else if (radio.equals("Enum")){
                    total = total + 0;
                }
                else if (radio.equals("integer")){
                    total = total + 0;
                }
                else if (radio.equals("Integer")){
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                else{
                    total = total + 0;
                }


                System.out.println(radio);

                return "results";

    }
```

the jsp that should post what result they get. The session.getAttribute bit works just not ${total}

```
<p>Good day <%= session.getAttribute("uname") %> </p>
<p>For question 1 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q1") %> </p>
<p>For question 2 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q2") %> </p>
<p>For question 3 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q3") %> </p>
<p>For question 4 you chose <%= session.getAttribute("q4") %> </p>

<section>
    <p>Total score: ${total} /4</p>
```

Comment: You can use a servlet to process data and send it back to the client. Not sure how this relates to spring-mvc though.

Comment: im trying to do this project in spring. and is a servlet the java classes with stuff like this in: @RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String results(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)

Comment: ps how do you write a servlet in spring? @Compass-

Comment: pps sorry for putting codes in comments

Comment: The same way you'd write it outside of Spring, as servlets do not require Spring to work.

Comment: but servlets are a lot tidier in spring...

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form to a controller, call the if statement and put the result in a ModelAndView, that your controller returns.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView results(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

      ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
      // set name of next view ...
      mav.setViewName("results");

      // handle if...

      // add results to next view ...
      mav.addObject("anyNameYouWant", yourObject);
      return mav;

}
```

Comment: i have submitted and then called if statement. what do you mean by M&V bit? will post code in question so you can see

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html

Comment: sorry i just realized my last comment seemed like a demand. i meant my code is in the question now lol. 
but anyhow, i kind of understand your code. but where do i return the results.jsp page?

Comment: and where do i define radio which is in my if statement for the string comparisons

Comment: and finally, what should go in place of yourObject?